# Which is the better choice here? Present perfect continuous or past simple?

Tags: past-simple, present-perfect-progressive

Today is Sunday and I don't feel well because I have been drinking three days in a row: Thursday, Friday and Saturday.

The drinking has stopped, but I can still feel its effect, so present perfect continuous is the appropriate tense to use.

On the other hand, the drinking happened in the past, even if it is a very recent past. So I'm in doubt about which tense to use. I feel that If I use past simple it makes it sound like it has no effect now, it is a past event. Am I correct about this?

Answer (score 1):

Sentence in the question:

"Today is Sunday and I **don't feel well** because I have been drinking three days in a row: Thursday, Friday and Saturday."

**On Sunday**, you would say:

"Today is Sunday and **I'm not feeling well** because **I drank** three days in a row: Thursday, Friday and Saturday."

**I drank** can also be: I was drinking for three days in a row.

The present perfect does not apply  here.

Answer (score 0):

**Present perfect continuous** is sometimes used for an action already finished. In such cases the continuity of the activity is emphasized as an explanation of something.

> Why are your clothes so wet? - I have been watering the garden.

In your sentence **I have been drinking for three days** is an explanation for why you don't feel well, so its better you use **present perfect continuous**.

Comment: Would you be so kind as to write the pronunciation of your first name for me? The syllabification? Thanks. :)

Comment: chii-ti-zae  it is a hindi word for horizon

Comment: @Kshitij Singh In your example of the wet clothes less time has passed, I think. You don't walk around in wet clothes for hours, whereas i my example hours have passed. Do you think that makes a difference?